# Put a vector image on the right of a table and adjust its height to the table height

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, positioning, scaling

I have a table

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X p{70pt}
\toprule
stuff1&stuff2\\ \midrule
stuff3&stuff4\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

and i would like to insert on its right a vector image with fixed width and adjust its height in such a way that the upper edge of the image is aligned to the \toprule of the table and the bottom edge    of the image is aligned to the \bottomrule. I made many attempts but all of them failed.

**EDIT:**

Both of the solutions proposed give me layout problems on the pages following the one of the table, in particular the effect i observe is that the left margin is set to 0. Here below i put the full code hoping that you can find the cause. My aim is still the same the only thing changing is that i want the image on the left of the table.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{layout}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{layouts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}






\definecolor{my_red}{RGB}{213,3,14}


%section
\titleformat{\section}
{\color{my_red}\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
{\color{my_red}\thesection}{1em}{}
%subsection
\titleformat{\subsection}
{\color{my_red}\normalfont\large\bfseries}
{\color{my_red}\thesubsection}{1em}{}
%subsubsection
\titleformat{\subsubsection}
{\color{my_red}\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}
{\color{my_red}\thesubsubsection}{1em}{}



%Margins
\setlength{\hoffset}{-1in}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}
\setlength{\marginparpush}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{0pt}
\setlength{\textwidth}{18cm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\voffset}{1.46cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{-1in}
\setlength{\headheight}{1in}
\setlength{\headsep}{30pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{21.78696cm}


\newsavebox\mysavebox

\begin{document}

%
%FIRST PAGE
%
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot[L]{stuff}
\fancyfoot[C]{}
\fancyfoot[R]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}


\begin{adjustbox}{gstore=\mysavebox}
\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{ X p{70pt}}
\toprule
stuff1&stuff2\\ \midrule
stuff3&stuff4\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\end{adjustbox}
\adjustimage{height=\ht\mysavebox+\dp\mysavebox, width=1cm, raise=-\dp\mysavebox}{margin.pdf}

\newpage    

%
%OTHER PAGES  
%


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyhead[R]{
        \begin{picture}(65,0)
        \includegraphics[ width=70pt,left]{Logo.pdf}
        \end{picture}
        }
\fancyhead[L]{
        {data}\vspace{40pt}
        }
\fancyhead[C]{
        title\vspace{40pt}
        }
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[LE]{stuff}
\fancyfoot[RE]{}
\fancyfoot[LO]{stuff \\ stuff}
\fancyfoot[RO]{\phantom{internal}\\ \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1pt}

\section{Section}
{alfhlkjhgldsfhgjh}\footnote{section}
textheight in cm: \printinunitsof{cm}\prntlen{\textheight}
\subsection{Subsection}
{alfhlkjhgldsfhgjh}\footnote{subsection}

\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
{alfhlkjhgldsfhgjh}\footnote{subsubsection}

\begin{itemize}
\item[{\color{my_red}$\bullet$} ]stuff
\item[{\color{my_red}$\bullet$} ]stuff
\end{itemize}

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt} 
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|X|}
\toprule
  \textbf{Symptom} & \textbf{Metric} \\ \midrule
Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data & ATFD is more than a few\\ \midrule
Class that is large and complex & WMC is high\\ \midrule
Class that has a lot of methods that only operate on a proper subset of the instance variable set & TCC is low\\ \midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|c|X|}
\toprule
\textbf{Version} &   \textbf{Date} & \textbf{Metric} \\
\midrule
01&28-01-2019& Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data \\
\midrule
01&28-01-2019& Class that is large and complex \\
\midrule
01&28-01-2019& Class that has a lot of methods that only operate on a proper subset of the instance variable set \\
\midrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[H]
\setlength\aboverulesep{0pt}
\setlength\belowrulesep{0pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|c|X|c|c|X|}
\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{|c|}{Stuff}\\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
28-01-2019& Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data& \multirow{2}{*}{\phantom{a}}  &28-01-2019& Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data \\ \cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
28-01-2019& Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data& & 28-01-2019& Class that has many accessor methods and accesses a lot of external data \\
\cline{1-2}\cline{4-5}
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Please always provide your code as a full, compilable example document. This makes it so much easier to code a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the table in a box and use the box dimensions to scale the image.
This can be achieved in a simple way with the `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for example code

\newsavebox\mysavebox
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\medskip

\begin{adjustbox}{gstore=\mysavebox}
\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{ X p{70pt}}
\toprule
stuff1&stuff2\\ \midrule
stuff3&stuff4\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\end{adjustbox}
\adjustimage{height=\ht\mysavebox+\dp\mysavebox,width=.2\textwidth,raise=-\dp\mysavebox}{example-image}

\medskip


\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you want to draw the vector graphic using TeX code then change the `\adjustimage` to `{adjustbox}`. However, un that case you might want to use the box dimensions as TikZ settings instead to avoid distortions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for example code

\newsavebox\mysavebox
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\medskip

\begin{adjustbox}{gstore=\mysavebox}
\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{ X p{70pt}}
\toprule
stuff1&stuff2\\ \midrule
stuff3&stuff4\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\end{adjustbox}
\begin{adjustbox}{height=\ht\mysavebox+\dp\mysavebox,width=.2\textwidth,raise=\depth-\dp\mysavebox}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \draw (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}

\medskip


\blindtext

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you want to position the image on the left instead, you just need to change the `gstore` key to `gstore*` to make `adjustbox` not insert the saved box right away. Then place `\usebox\mysavebox` after the `\includegraphics` command. You need to watch hidden spaces here which might be added to the left of the image. Best is to end some lines with `%` to mask the line breaks which are turned into spaces.
If you want a specific distance between the image and the table change the space with `\hspace{<length>}`.

\documentclass{article}

```
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{mwe}% just for example code

\newsavebox\mysavebox
\begin{document}

\blindtext

\medskip

\begin{adjustbox}{gstore*=\mysavebox}
\begin{tabularx}{.8\textwidth}{ X p{70pt}}
\toprule
stuff1&stuff2\\ \midrule
stuff3&stuff4\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}%
\end{adjustbox}%
\adjustimage{height=\ht\mysavebox+\dp\mysavebox,width=.19\textwidth,raise=-\dp\mysavebox}{example-image} \usebox\mysavebox

\medskip


\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! how can i put it on the left insteoad of the right?

Comment: @student: I updated my answer to show that.

Comment: Thank you very much @Martin the effect is indeed the one i need. I still have layout problems and i can't understand why, i reported the full code in the EDIT. If i comment the part with with your suggestion the layout of following pages is ok, if i uncomment it the following pages have distorted layout, can you help me pls?

Comment: found the error, my bad! it was in the margin settings. Sorry!

Answer (score 3):

You can use zref to store the positions and use them to calculate the height:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,graphicx,zref-savepos,booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[b]{Xp{70pt}}
\noalign{\zsaveposy{top}}\toprule
stuff1&stuff2\\ \midrule
stuff3&stuff4\\ \bottomrule\noalign{\zsaveposy{bottom}}
\end{tabularx}%
\makebox[0pt][l]{\raisebox{0pt}[0pt][0pt]{%
\includegraphics[height=
\dimexpr\zposy{top}sp-\zposy{bottom}sp]
{example-image-duck}}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Many thanks, this is exactly what i need! Unfortunately i'm experiencing a side effect of the solution you proposed. Indeed it modifies the layout of the following pages. How can i overcome this effect?

Comment: There is nothing in the code that modifies the layout.

Comment: i really don't know why this happens